# Add translation variable to prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have a question concerning Prestashop 1.7 translation variables.

Actually, "**how to add translation variable to Prestashop**"?
I need only some translation variables ***I can modify(content) then in BO*** (International>Translations>than I can modify the content of variable)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme : {l s='Your trad d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'} 
"Shop.Theme.Catalog" depends on where you are.

In module PHP : $this->l('Your trad');

In module template : {l s="your trad" mod="yourmodulename"}

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't like to make my module, I like just to add 5-10 translations on a custom .tpl page

Comment: In your theme : {l s='Your trad d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'} "Shop.Theme.Catalog" depends on where you are.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it